# Proper way to pass same pointer to 2 threads(each thread runs another operation)

Tags: c++

What is the proper way to pass a pointer to 2 threads that each one of the threads runs another operation?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <random>


struct Unit {

    Unit(uint64_t id_) :
        id(id_),
        v(1000000000)
    {}

    uint64_t id;
    std::vector<int> v;
};

void operation1(Unit* unit) {
    std::cout << "Hello operation1";
}

void operation2(Unit* unit) {
    std::cout << "Hello operation2";
}

void operationMain() {
    Unit* unit = new Unit(1);
    std::thread at1(&operation1, unit);
    std::thread at2(&operation2, unit);
    at1.detach();
    at2.detach();
}

int main123(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::thread t(&operationMain);
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my code, and I think I have a memory leak because 'unit' is passing to several operations in different threads.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The threads are irrelevant and a red herring. If you do `new` without a corresponding `delete` you have a memory leak.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using smart pointers, particularly ```std::shared_ptr```? The rest of the code seems to use C++11 features

Comment: Where should I add the delete? before or after detach?

Comment: Please read up on the proper use of smart pointers. Using new and delete is rarely used in modern C++

Comment: Can you provide an example of smart pointers based on my code please?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to not use `detach()` but use `join()` **or** not share the object **or** create one of in (say) the `at1` thread, `detach()` it and create `at2` the as a thread within that second thread and join in the `at1` thread or allocated a `shared_ptr<>` but shared ownership is way down the list as 'avoid where possible'.

`detach()` means a thread executes independently and you cannot call `join()` on a detached thread so you have no suitable point at which to cause the `delete` of the dynamically allocated `Unit` to take place in the calling thread.

It's not clear from the question why you've allocated shared resources and then called `detach()`.

On my machine I get no output (even with a realistic size for the vector) because the `main()` thread ends before the detach threads do anything meaningful.

This should work fine:

```
void operationMain() {
       std::unique_ptr<Unit> unit (std::make_unique<Unit>(1));
       std::thread at1(operation1, unit.get());
       std::thread at2(operation2, unit.get());
       at1.join();        
       at2.join();
       //at1 and at2 have terminated and the unique_ptr destructor will delete the object (RAII).
}
```